# PL/SQL Using SELECT inside of CONDITION

Tags: windows, oracle, docker, powershell, plsql

I've installed `Oracle` Instance inside of `docker` container and I put `sql` script whitch runs when a container starts:

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM...
...
CMD powershell echo @C:\scripts\entrypoint.sql | sqlplus -S sys/password as sysdba
```

`entrypoint.sql`:

```
set serveroutput on format wrapped;
declare
userexist integer;
db_schema_version varchar2(20);
begin
  select count(*) into userexist from dba_users where username='DEV';
  if (userexist = 0) then
    dbms_output.put_line('SCHEMA NOT FOUND!');
    dbms_output.put_line('CONNECTION STRING: ' || 'sqlplus sys/password@localhost/ORA193 as sysdba');
  elsif (userexist = 1) then
    dbms_output.put_line('SCHEMA FOUND!');
    select DB_SCHEMA_VERSION into db_schema_version from DEV.VER_INFO where CODE = 'CORE';
    dbms_output.put_line('DB_SCHEMA_VERSION: ' || db_schema_version);
    dbms_output.put_line('CONNECTION STRING: ' || 'sqlplus DEV/password@localhost/ORA193');
  end if;
end;
/
```

The issue is that query `select DB_SCHEMA_VERSION into db_schema_version from DEV.VER_INFO where CODE = 'CORE';` is executing even if `elsif` condition is `false`

What is the correct way of writing `PL/SQL` to get `select` query executed only in case of condition is `true`?

Comment: @WalterMitty This is PL/SQL, so the scope of the `then` statement ends at the next `end if`, and there's no script interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't that the query is being executed if the condition is false.  The problem is that the PL/SQL block has to be compiled before it can be executed.  And the compilation fails if it has a reference to an object that doesn't exist (if you posted the error message, it would be clear that it's a compilation error not a runtime error).

If you want to reference an object that might not exist, you'd want to use dynamic SQL.  Something like

```
execute immediate 'select db_schema_version from dev.ver_info'
             into db_schema_version;
```

would work in this case.  In more complicated cases, you'd want to build the SQL statement in a local variable that you can log for debugging purposes or potentially use the `dbms_sql` package.